# Limit log sizes in particual ufw's logs

Tags: logs, ufw

(Ubuntu 14.04 x86)

I have enabled `ufw` and enabled logging (level low - the default). Even on low there is an entry about every second (it is accessible from the Internet - I guess just port scans trying their luck).

My concern is: the log file could grow over time taking up disk space I would rather have for other things. I could find no mention of what it is limited to in `ufw`'s man pages - is it limited? How can I limit it? More generally what strategy does Linux use for limiting logs such as `syslog`?

Answer (score 4):

There is separate daemon called `logrotated` that take care about rotating and deleting old logs. You should have config file for ufw in `/etc/logrotate.d/ufw`

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/ufw
/var/log/ufw.log
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d rsyslog reload >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```